# unable to get the expected answer for string palindrom

Tags: python

Every time i am geting else condition as true. If i pass input string as "ama" then code should give input string is palindrom. But i am getting string is not palindrom.
Input: ami
output: ami
Expected:string is palindrom

Input: amit
output: tima
Expected:string is n palindrom

```
def str_rev (input_str):
    print("input_str:", input_str)
    rev_str = " "
        for i in (input_str):
            rev_str = i + rev_str
    print("inp_str:", input_str)    
    print("rev_str:", rev_str)
    if (input_str == rev_str):
        print("string is palindrom")
    else:
        print("string is not palindrom")
    return  rev_str       
        
str = input ("Enter the string:")
print("org string:", str)
final_str= str_rev (str)
print("reverse string:", final_str)
```

Comment: An easier way to get the inverse of a string is to use `rev_str = input_str[::-1]` [link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_howto_reverse_string.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a quick glance, your formatting is off, but I think your problem is with white space. Change:

```
rev_str = " "
```

to

```
rev_str = ""
```

to get rid of that extra white space.

In fact, you can trim your strings before comparing, with the `.strip()` command to remove any leading or trailing white space.

```
'  hi '.strip() --> 'hi'
```

Answer (score 1):

A palindrome is a word that is the same backwards and forwards. Therefore `ami` is not a palindrome.

Comment: but if i give input as : ama then also it print string not palindrom

Comment: Try changing `rev_str = " "` to `rev_str = ""` that way it doesn't have a space

Answer (score 0):

you got bug at line 3
rev_str = " "
should be
rev_str = "" #empty string

otherwise, you create a new string with empty space at the start
Jarda

Comment: Please consider providing some source code to support the given answer explaining show how it solves the problem.